# Cakephp3 redirect in beforeFilter is not working

Tags: redirect, controller, cakephp-3.0, before-filter

When I add the $this->redirect statement inside a beforeFilter of a controller and return afterwards, the redirection is being ignored. When I move the redirect statement inside an action of the controller, it works fine. Does someone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    if( true ){ //if a sample condition is true
        return $this->redirect([
            'controller' => 'test',
            'action' => 'action'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177050/cakephp-3-redirect-in-beforefilter-of-parent-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was returning the response object only from the beforeFilter in the AppController the redirect did not work.
For further details check out https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6705.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to your own question. It helped.

Answer (score -1):

If anything solution does not work do following code.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
if( true ){ //if a sample condition is true
    $url = '/'; //set url here
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location="'.$url.'"';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a short explanation.