# Cakephp 3 redirect in beforeFilter of parent class

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-3.0

In our CakePHP 3 application we found a different behaviour. We're sure that it worked well in CakePHP 2, so I suppose something changed in new version.

When user visits this url: `/b2controller/myMethod`, these methods run:

```
AppController::beforeFilter()  
BController::beforeFilter()  
B2Controller::beforeFilter()  
B2Controller::myMethod()  
B2Controller::myMethod2()
```

then user is redirected to this url `/ccontroller/myMethod10/`

But we need this:

When user visits 
`/b2controller/myMethod` and `$isOk` condition is `true`, then redirect user to `/ccontroller/myMethod10/`, without running `BController::beforeFilter()`, `B2Controller::beforeFilter()`, `B2Controller::myMethod()` and `BController::MyMethod2()`.

Our minimal code is like this:

```
class AppController {
  function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
        // set $isOk variable
        if ($isOk == TRUE) {
           return $this->redirect('/ccontroller/myMethod10/');
        }
        $aa=1;
        $ab=2;
  }
}

class BController extends AppController {
  function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $a=1;
    $b=2;
  }

  function myOtherMethod() {
      myOtherMethod2();
  }

  function myOtherMethod2() {
      ...
      ...
  }
}

class B2Controller extends BController {
  function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $m1=1;
    $m2=2;
  }

  function myMethod() {
      myMethod2();
  }

  function myMethod2() {
      ...
      ...
  }
}

class CController extends AppController {
  function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
  }

  function myMethod10() {
      ...
      ...
      ...
  }
}
```

How can I make user to redirect to another controller action, from the beforeFilter of main class ? Note that redirect occurs. But user is redirected after calling `myMethod()` and `myMethod2()`.

Also note that there is other controllers like `CController` that uses beforeFilter redirect behaviour.

Comment: Try returning `parent::beforeFilter ($event)` in `BController`. `Controller::redirect` returns a `Response` object, if you don't return it in the `beforeFilter` call, Cake [won't be able to detect](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_startupProcess) that you want to do a redirection.

Comment: You mean like this? `class BController extends AppController {
  function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    return parent::beforeFilter($event);
  }
}`

Comment: Yes. I am not sure at all, but looking at the source of `startupProcess`, it looks like you need to return something in order to stop the request process.

Comment: I updated code. Assume that I change `BController::beforeFilter()` and add return inside that function. In that case if `$isOk` is false, then remaining codes inside `BController::beforeFilter()` will not work.

Comment: I was finally able to test your code on a working CakePHP installation, see my answer.

Comment: If my answer is not working for you, could you explain what is not working? Because with the available information, it is hard to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your code works. But I needed to update minimal code to show our system. Our application can use BController, B2Controller and CController independently. So we need a more general solution that minimizes code duplication.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your last edit. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here are 3 methods that works:

#### Method 1 - Override `startupProcess` in your controller(s)

Override the `startupProcess` method of `AppController`:

```
// In your AppController
public function startupProcess() {
    // Compute $isOk
    if ($isOk) {
        return $this->redirect('/c/myMethod10');
    }
    return parent::startupProcess();
}
```

This is a short and quite clean method, so I would go for this one if you can. If this does not fit your needs, see below.

**Note:** If you use this method, your components may not be initialized when you compute `$isOk` since the initialization is done by `parent::startupProcess`.

#### Method 2 - Send the response from `AppController`:

One easy but not really clean way may be to send the response from  `AppController::beforeFilter`:

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    // Compute $isOk
    if ($isOk) {
        $this->response = $this->redirect('/c/myMethod10');
        $this->response->send();
        die();
    }
}
```

#### Method 3 - Use [`Dispatcher Filters`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html)

A more "clean" way would be to use [`Dispatcher Filters`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html):

In **`src/Routing/Filter/RedirectFilter.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Routing\Filter;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;

class RedirectFilter extends DispatcherFilter {

    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event) {
        // Compute $isOk
        if ($isOk) {
            $response = $event->data['response'];
            // The code bellow mainly comes from the source of Controller.php
            $response->statusCode(302);
            $response->location(\Cake\Routing\Router::url('/c/myMethod10', true));
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

In **`config/bootstrap.php`**:

```
DispatcherFactory::add('Redirect');
```

And you can remove the redirection in your `AppController`. This may be the cleanest way if you are able to compute `$isOk` from the `DispatcherFilter`.

Note that if you have `beforeRedirect` event, these will not be triggered with this method.

---

**Edit:** This was my previous answer which does not work very well if you have multiple `B`-like controllers.

You need to return the `Response` object returned by `$this->redirect()`. One way of achieving this is by doing the following:

```
class BController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
        $result = parent::beforeFilter($event);
        if ($result instanceof \Cake\Network\Response) {
            return $result;
        } 
        // Your stuff
    }

}
```

The code bellow the `if` is executed only if there was no redirection (`parent::beforeFilter($event)` did not return a `Response` object).

**Note:** I do not know how you compute `isOk`, but be careful of infinite redirection loop if you call `$this->redirect()` when calling `/ccontroller/mymethod10`.

Comment: It method 2, is `die()` is good or can `$this->response->stop()` be used for same thing ?

Comment: @trante Actually `$this->response->stop($status)` is strictly equivalent to `exit($status)` (see source), and `exit` is equivalent to `die` so the code would be equivalent, I am not sure this is a very clean method for doing what you want.

Comment: method 2 worked fine for me, thanks a lot, made my day