# Redirect from AppController::initialize without running child code

Tags: inheritance, redirect, middleware, cakephp-3.x

Using **CakePHP 3.9**:
I'm trying to redirect a user to a page where he/she can choose which organisation to log in with, if he hasn't chosen any. To make sure this happens on every page, I added the code in the `AppController::initialize()` method. The redirect statement doesn't (directly) execute though. It still runs the code in the child controller (`OrganisationsController extends AppController`), where it bumps into the problem that no organisation was selected (duh).

I have tried the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190873/1973005), but it seems to be a little outdated and/or not working.

Here is my original `AppController` code:

```php
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();

    if( $this->getRequest()->getSession()->check('organisation.selected') ) {
        $organisation_id = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('organisation.selected');
        $this->loadModel('Organisations');
        $organisation = $this->Organisations->get($organisation_id);
        $this->organisation = [
            'id' => $organisation['id'],
            'name' => $organisation['name'],
        ];
    }
    else {
        if( !$this->isSuperuser && !empty($this->Auth->user('id')) && !($this->request->getParam('controller') == "Organisations" && $this->request->getParam('action') == 'switch') ) {
            // THIS DOESN'T REDIRECT:
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Organisations', 'action' => 'switch', '?' => ['redirect' => $path]]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to only change the `AppController` code, since there are too many other controllers/actions that depend on the $this->organisation to be set. Writing code in all these places would not be clean.

#### 1. Override `startupProcess` in your controller(s)

I guess this should be 'Override `initialize`' in my case, but the following has no effect:

```php
else {
    if( !$this->isSuperuser && !empty($this->Auth->user('id')) && !($this->request->getParam('controller') == "Organisations" && $this->request->getParam('action') == 'switch') ) {
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Organisations', 'action' => 'switch', '?' => ['redirect' => $path]]);
    }
}
return parent::initialize(); // NO EFFECT :(
```

#### 2. Send the response from `AppController`

I didn't try this, because it is not a clean solution as the author of the answer already states himself.

#### 3. Use [`Dispatcher Filters`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html)

The [CakePHP documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/dispatch-filters.html) says this is deprecated, and should be handled with [middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html) now. I couldn't find how though.

Comment: The `initialize` function is not meant to return anything, hence why your attempt to redirect from there is having no effect. When you say you couldn't find how to do this with middleware, is your problem with understanding how to use middleware in general, or how to implement this specific thing in middleware?

Comment: Ah, that would explain it, thanks. I haven't really used middleware yet, but since it exists of multiple levels, I also wouldn't know in what place to put this redirect. Could you show me a little more into the right direction?

Comment: There's no way to give a definitive list of what order things need to be done in. If a middleware A relies on something that B does, or might not happen depending on results from B, then A has to be loaded after B. So, for example, middleware for parsing form contents has to happen before authentication, because authentication might need that form data to be parsed already. Your example code is looking at the logged in user, so it would need to come after authentication. Where it might fit other than that very much depends on what other middleware you might use.